# How to add these sets of symbols to LaTex?

Tags: symbols

[image: A subset of Argam Numerals that are used for the extention of base-10 Hindu-Arabic numerals]

I need to add these symbols to LaTex while still kinda fitting the default LaTex font. I have added some of the symbols as

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\ten{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{2}}
\def\eleven{\reflectbox{7}}
\def\thirteen{\reflectbox{6}}
\def\fourteen{\reflectbox{3}}
```

but i couldn't do the rest of it

Comment: Where did the image come from?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides https://numerals.fandom.com/wiki/De_Vlieger_Argam

Comment: Thanks. As these do not belong to any unicode script, there is no easy solution. 1) make a font out of the individual numerals or b) use tikz to generate at least some of them. If it is a one off you looking at , you can use the cut images, as is the simpler solution.

Comment: You can use fontcreator to make a font out of the images https://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator

Comment: Or you could try and get an existing font. From a quick search it seems like none are available, though [some exist](https://numerals.fandom.com/wiki/User_blog:Dozenalism/List_of_known_Argam_fonts) (with partial coverage, but enough for you). Maybe one of the authors is willing to share their font with you if you ask them.

Comment: @schtandard that is probably what i'll end up doing, thank you all